# How can I ensure an if loop waits for and receives a result before running the next if loop in sequence

Tags: javascript, function, return

I have a javascript function where if loops are not following each other sequentially. I need them to run one after the other. The second loop should not run until the first loop has finished, because it deals with the output of the first.

1. I use an if loop (loop 1) to call a function in a child iframe (this frame contains mapping elements, and I can't reasonably combine it with the parent frame). This part is working as intended.
2. The function in the iframe is triggered, and it makes a call to an external service, and awaits a response. When it receives a response it passes either "error" or "ok" back to the parent function by using the 'return' function. This part is working as intended.
3. The parent receives the response, sets a variable and then should continue on with the next if statement (loop 2) that does something else.

What actually happens  is that loop 1 runs, then loop 2 also runs, and loop 2 returns results before loop 1 - which screws things up as loop 2 is meant to be dealing with thee results from loop 1.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.gv-button-delete', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();  //prevent submission
        console.log('Intercepted delete button request');
        var delLoc = "";
        (function ($) {
            var delLoc2 = $('.gv-button-delete').attr("href"); //capture default action, because we need the time-valid nonce
            delLoc = delLoc2;
        }(jQuery));

        var objID = document.getElementById("input_4_40").value;
        objID = parseInt(objID);
        var iframe = document.getElementById("MapFrame1");
        var result = "";
        if (iframe) { //1st if loop that collects the answer
            var iframeContent = (iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument);
            var result = iframeContent.WriteLog(objID); //call the function from the iframe, and hopefully wait for a result. 
            console.log(result);
        }
        if (result == "error") { //the second if loop
            console.log("Step 5")
            console.log("There was an error with removing the feature");
        } else if (result == "ok") {
            console.log("Step 5")
            console.log("The spatial delete completed correctly");
        } else {
            console.log("Step 5")
            console.log("unexpected result of spatial delete")
        }

    });
```

the iframe code, becuase it's useful for context.

```
function WriteLog(objID){
        var retireFeatureID = hotspots.getFeature(objID);
        var successStatus = "";
        retireFeatureID.feature.properties["SystemStatus"] = "Deleted";
        hotspots.updateFeature(retireFeatureID.feature, function (err, response) { //This is a syncronous call to another service
            if (err) {
                console.log("Step 3")
                console.log(err);
                successStatus = "error";
                console.log("successStatus is: " + successStatus);
            } else {
                console.log("Step 3")
                console.log(response);
                successStatus = "ok";
                console.log("successStatus is: " + successStatus);
            }

        });
        console.log("Step 4")
        console.log("Updated the status of feature: " + objID);
        console.log("child iframe has variable successStatus as: " + successStatus);
        return successStatus;
    }
```

What actually happens is that the console results look like:

Step 4

Step 5

Step 3

The second loop is returning before the first loop has finished and returned a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be due to how callbacks and the javascript event loop work in general, and steps 4 and 5 will be executed first before step 3.

The function response callback will be placed at the end of call stack, which causes the remaining code (step 4 onwards and second if loop) to be executed without waiting for the callback to complete despite the other service code being synchronous.

I would suggest you to either convert the service function to one with a direct return and if possible not using callbacks, or changing the `WriteLog` function to a callback function by adding a callback argument and invoking it once you get the response from the other service.

[JavaScript Event Loop Explained](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/javascript-event-loop-explained-4cd26af121d4)

Comment: Thanks. I'm still pretty green on javascript. I assume I'd need to be introducing the callback somewhere around the var result = iframeContent.WriteLog(objID); line, but I must admit I'm not sure how. 
That line is setting the variable by calling a function. Any suggestions on how I would turn it into a callback?

Comment: Although Sandkalp's response was probablythe best described soltuion that I've seen on stack overflow, I'm going to mark Willi123yao's response as the correct one because: The Async-await still ran in to the same error as my original code, and the While loop code. 

In the end the correct result was found by calling a function that contained the second if loop. Loop 1 calls a child page, child page has a function. When child page function returns a result it calls the second if loop and hands over the result. That was the only way I could get the sequencing to work.

Answer (score 3):

`async-await` might the answer to your problem.

Here is how it works.

You define a function that sends a response with some delay (maybe because of a network call or something).

```
async function f() {
  // Make network call and return value
  return value;
}
```

And you call this function with an await.

```
var valueRequired = await f();
if(valueRequired == something) {
   doSomeWork();
}
```

I hope this was clear.

Reference: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Do note that this is not compatible in older browsers, as this is a rather modern JS construct.

Comment: That's a very clear and succinct way of describing that concept. Thank you!

I'm getting an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Just trying to come up with a jsfiddle/codepen for it. The gist is here: https://gist.github.com/anakaine/e0b00aae0269e1d7e41921bcf85cd197

Comment: Thats because you can only use await inside a function that was defined with async. In your case you'd need to define the callback of this line `jQuery(document).on('click', '.gv-button-delete', function (e)` as async like so: `jQuery(document).on('click', '.gv-button-delete', async function (e)`

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. The function runs now, though still having the out of order execution issue. I tried moving the second lot of if statements inside the first loop, and after the await statement, but that didn't seem to resolve the matter. https://gist.github.com/anakaine/c787fd4cb524630063d1a68b1f7f3b9e .and I subsequently moved it back outside.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a flag. This flag can go right after `console.log(result)`. The 2nd if block can be inside a `while` that does not allow for the code to proceed before this flag is `true`. This ensures that your 2nd `if` won't happen before the 1st.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this by setting a variable as flag = 0; before if (iframe) {, and then setting flag = 1; after console.log(result);. I then placed a while (flag == 1) { loop around the if (result ="something"); loops. Unfortunately I'm still seeing the code run out of order, in the same sequence as before. The gist is here: https://gist.github.com/anakaine/1f45ee78ecbdda831a11e94e15fe9b25